# Why is it important to extends Thread Class In Java to create parameterised constructor

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand what happen behind the scenes in Java Thread class - Here is the scenario

**Scneario 1**

I have main class like this

```
public class LoadBalancerUpStreamManagement extends Thread{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        LoadBalancerUpStreamManagement loadBalancerUpStreamManagement  = new LoadBalancerUpStreamManagement();
        loadBalancerUpStreamManagement.start();
        
    }
}
```

In the above scenario, as we have extended `Thread` class hence, its `start method` has also inherited. When we call the `start method` on object `loadBalancerUpStreamManagement`, it start and JVM internally called the `run` method on the new thread. Make sense so far.

**Now consider another scenario**

```
public class LoadBalancerUpStreamManagement extends Thread{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        LoadBalancer elb = new LoadBalancer();

        new Thread(elb);  ---> 2. It gives me constructor error - Can not resolve constructor Thread(LoadBalancer) 
    }
}

class LoadBalancer { ------> 1. I have not extended the Thread class here 


}
```

I am not able to understand, why is it important to `extends Thread Class` - Which OOPS concept is breaking and what is going on behind the scene?

If I extends `Thread` class then it all good.

```
public class LoadBalancerUpStreamManagement extends Thread{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        LoadBalancer elb = new LoadBalancer();
        new Thread(elb);  ------> 2. It is all good here. 
    }
}

class LoadBalancer extends Thread{ ---> 1. Extended Thread Class 


}
```

Comment: In modern Java, we rarely address the `Thread`  class directly. Define your task as a `Runnable` or `Callable`. Submit an instance to an `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 1):

Thread class has few constructors available, one of which is `Runnable`

```
Thread(Runnable target)
```

full list can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Another important thing is that `Thread` class implements `Runnable` interface.
Therefore whichever class extends `Thread` also gets to implement `Runnable` with the method `run` that you mentioned. That is why you can pass your classes that extended `Thread` in that constructor - because they are instanceof `Runnable`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code for class `java.lang.Thread`<sup>1</sup>.
It has a `Runnable` member.

```
/* What will be run. */
private Runnable target;
```

However this member may be null. Hence class `Thread` also implements `Runnable`

```java
public class Thread implements Runnable
```

Now look at the code for method `run` in class `Thread`

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

If `target` is null, method `run` does nothing.
Therefore you have two options.

1. Assign a value to member `target` – which can only be done via one of the constructors of class `Thread`<sup>2</sup>. Note that this value can be an instance of any class that implements `Runnable`. It does not have to be another class that extends `Thread` and, since Java 8, it can also be a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

```java
public class LoadBalancerUpStreamManagement extends Thread{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        LoadBalancer elb = new LoadBalancer();
        new Thread(elb);
    }
}

class LoadBalancer implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Replace with your code.");
    }
}
```

OR

```java
public class LoadBalancerUpStreamManagement extends Thread{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Replace with your code.")); // lambda expression
    }
}
```

2. Write a class that extends `Thread` and overrides its `run` method (as you have done).

<sup>1</sup> The source code is included in the JDK. Look for file `src.zip` under the directory where you installed the JDK.

<sup>2</sup> Refer to *javadoc* for class [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html)